# unity to arduino serial crashing

Tags: unity-game-engine, arduino

i am new to unity and this website and im making a code for a arduino braccio++ where i can control the robot arm live from my laptop on unity. i found the model and alot of the code online but had to change it a bunch for my own use. when the arduino.write is called for the first time it seemingly works fine but after the delay and it is called again, the whole of unity stops and i cant do anything until i unplug the arduino. however the debug.log shows me it stops at the yeild waitforseconds but when i unplug it the debug.log up to the arduino.write show up.

the reason i think its the arduino.write and not the yeild waitforseconds is because when i take out the arduino.write it all runs fine but when its in the above happened. i will put my arduino and unity code below.

unity code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class ArduinoSerial : MonoBehaviour {
    public rotation servo1;
    public rotation2 servo2;
    public rotation3 servo3;
    public rotation4 servo4;
    public rotation5 servo5;
    public float delaySeconds = 1f;
    public string portName;
    SerialPort arduino;
    bool startCommands = false;
    bool ready = false;

    void Start () {
        arduino = new SerialPort (portName, 9600);
        arduino.Open ();

    }

    void Update () {

        Debug.Log ("broken");

        if (startCommands == false) 
            Debug.Log ("broken3");
            StartCoroutine (SendCommands ());
        }

    IEnumerator SendCommands () {
        Debug.Log ("broken4");
        startCommands = true;
        //yield return null;
        if (startCommands == true){
            Debug.Log ("broken8");
        }
        //arduino.Close();
        //arduino.Open();
        Debug.Log ("broken7");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delaySeconds);
        Debug.Log ("broken5");

        arduino.Close();
        arduino.Open();

        ready = arduino.IsOpen;

        if (ready == false){
            try{
                arduino.Open();
            }
            catch{
                Debug.Log ("no serial");
            }
        }

        Debug.Log ("broken1");

        if (ready == true) {

                Debug.Log ("broken2");

                string str;

                string thetaBaseStr = (Mathf.RoundToInt(servo1.eulerAngY)).ToString("000");
                string thetaShoulderStr = (Mathf.RoundToInt(servo2.servo2angle)).ToString("000");
                string thetaElbowStr = (Mathf.RoundToInt(servo3.servo3angle)).ToString("000");
                string thetaWristVerticalStr = (Mathf.RoundToInt(servo4.servo4angle)).ToString("000");
                string thetaWristRotationStr = (Mathf.RoundToInt(servo5.servo5angle)).ToString("000");

                str = thetaBaseStr + thetaShoulderStr + thetaElbowStr + thetaWristVerticalStr + thetaWristRotationStr + "\n";

                Debug.Log ("Send Serial: " + str);

                try{
                    arduino.Write (str);
                }
                catch{
                    Debug.Log ("transmission failed");
                }

                Debug.Log ("broken6");
                
        
        }
        startCommands = false;
        ready = false;

    }
}
```

```
/*
  simpleMovements.ino

  This  sketch simpleMovements shows how they move each servo motor of Braccio

  Created on 18 Nov 2015
  by Andrea Martino

  This example is in the public domain.
*/

#include <Braccio++.h>

int stepDelay = 20;
int m1 = 90;
int m2 = 45;
int m3 = 180;
int m4 = 180;
int m5 = 90;
int m6 = 10;
char incomingByte;

int row = 0;
int row1 = 0;
bool flipped = false;

char inData[25];
bool isRead = false;
int index1 = 0;

int array1[20][6];

int buttonpin = 2;

void setup() {
  //Initialization functions and set up the initial position for Braccio
  //All the servo motors will be positioned in the "safety" position:
  //Base (M1):90 degrees
  //Shoulder (M2): 45 degrees
  //Elbow (M3): 180 degrees
  //Wrist vertical (M4): 180 degrees
  //Wrist rotation (M5): 90 degrees
  //gripper (M6): 10 degrees
  Braccio.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(buttonpin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  /*
    Step Delay: a milliseconds delay between the movement of each servo.  Allowed values from 10 to 30 msec.
    M1=base degrees. Allowed values from 0 to 180 degrees
    M2=shoulder degrees. Allowed values from 15 to 165 degrees
    M3=elbow degrees. Allowed values from 0 to 180 degrees
    M4=wrist vertical degrees. Allowed values from 0 to 180 degrees
    M5=wrist rotation degrees. Allowed values from 0 to 180 degrees
    M6=gripper degrees. Allowed values from 10 to 73 degrees. 10: the toungue is open, 73: the gripper is closed.
  */
  delay(10);
  readSerialStr();

  if (Braccio.isButtonPressed_ENTER() == true){

    Braccio.moveTo(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6);
    row1 += 1;
    delay(2000);

  }

  delay(10);
}

void readSerialStr() {
  flipped = false;

  digitalWrite(buttonpin, HIGH);

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      char incomingByte = Serial.read();
    
    if (flipped = false){
      while (incomingByte != '\n' && isDigit(incomingByte)) {
        isRead = true;
        delay(10);
        inData[index1] = incomingByte;
        index1 += 1;
        incomingByte = Serial.read();
        digitalWrite(buttonpin, LOW);
      }
      inData[index1] = '\0';
    }
    Serial.end();
    Serial.begin(9600);
    
  }
  

  if (isRead) {
    char m1_char[4];
    char m2_char[4];
    char m3_char[4];
    char m4_char[4];
    char m5_char[4];
    char m6_char[4];

    m1_char[0] = inData[0];
    m1_char[1] = inData[1];
    m1_char[2] = inData[2];
    m1_char[3] = '\0';
    m2_char[0] = inData[3];
    m2_char[1] = inData[4];
    m2_char[2] = inData[5];
    m2_char[3] = '\0';
    m3_char[0] = inData[6];
    m3_char[1] = inData[7];
    m3_char[2] = inData[8];
    m3_char[3] = '\0';
    m4_char[0] = inData[9];
    m4_char[1] = inData[10];
    m4_char[2] = inData[11];
    m4_char[3] = '\0';
    m5_char[0] = inData[12];
    m5_char[1] = inData[13];
    m5_char[2] = inData[14];
    m5_char[3] = '\0';
    m6_char[0] = inData[15];
    m6_char[1] = inData[16];
    m6_char[2] = inData[17];
    m6_char[3] = '\0';

    m1 = atoi(m1_char);
    m2 = atoi(m2_char);
    m3 = atoi(m3_char);
    m4 = atoi(m4_char);
    m5 = atoi(m5_char);
    m6 = atoi(m6_char);


    isRead = false;
    index1 = 0;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: `flipped = false` will always be `false`.

Comment: @MikeCAT sorry alot of this will be for testing and that was too i just accidentaly left it in